# Help required on strong induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Given:
$a_{1} = a_{2}=1, a_{n} = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}, n>2$ for $n\in N$

Can someone explain how this equation simplifies to this answer? I don't understand this summation. 
$$6(2a_{k-2}+a_{k-3}) = 6a_{k-1}$$

Comment: No one can answer that question without knowing the definition of $a_{k}$.

Comment: im not looking for the value of 6a(k-1) but rather how this equation was simplified to get to this answer.......do you need the definition of ak to get this answer?

Comment: Usually $a_k$ represents the $k$'th term of some sequence of numbers. For example, you could have a sequence of numbers like this: $a_0, a_1, a_2, ..., a_{k-3}, a_{k-2}, a_{k-1}, a_k, a_{k+1}, ..., a_n$. So the equation you wrote can be interpreted as "6 times the sum of twice the (k-2)'th term and the (k-3)'th term is equal to 6 times the (k-1)'th term". You therefore need the definition of $a_k$ in order to be able to prove this for any particular sequence of numbers.

Comment: Yes, the definition of $(a_k)_{k\in \Bbb N}$ is needed. You can easily think of an example in which the equality doesn't hold.

Comment: Yes. I mean you could simplify to $12 a_{k-2} + 6a_{k-3}$ but that gives no information about why this equation holds.

Comment: This question shouldn't have been downvoted. The OP didn't ask better because he doesn't know better.

Comment: Take the Fibonacci Sequence as an example: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, .... In this sequence we can say: $a_k=a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}$. So the relationship between the terms of the sequence depends on the sequence.

Comment: Sorry I dont really understand how this works....it is part of a strong induction proof and the subscipts would be part of a sequence. I understand how the 6 carries from one side to the other but the 2a(k-2) + a(k-3) = a(k-1) doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It might be better to state the original induction question you are trying to prove.

Comment: Ok I will write it up and post the induction.....

Comment: I am not very familiar with the conventions of the forum but I posted an answer that has the original theorem  that I am proving.

Comment: @NightMarcher: The convention here is that only answers to the question (or big steps toward an answer) go as quote "Answers". If you realize you were missing a key bit of information, you should edit your post; if you want to ask another question, see this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11400/what-to-do-if-you-have-a-question-about-a-problem-you-already-asked?cb=1 .

Comment: Ok....I will do that in the future...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I will repeat my answer here.

Given: $a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$

Let: $n=k-1$

Therefore: $a_{k-1}=2a_{k-2}+a_{k-3}$
Therefore: $6a_{k-1}=6(2a_{k-2}+a_{k-3})$

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a recurrence relationship. Unless you have some other equation, I would say this is a definition, not a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the theorem for the induction question:

$$
 a_{1} = a_{2}=1, a_{n} = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}, n>2, \ then \ a_{n}<6a_{n-2}, n \ge 5 \ and \ n\in N
$$

Comment: OK, so you are given that $a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. Therefore, let $n=k-1$ and you will get: $a_{k-1}=2a_{k-2}+a_{k-3}$.

Comment: Yes....sorry for the typo

Comment: No problem. Hopefully you can now see how the expression was simplified?

Comment: so yes i understand how to substitute for the k+1 term....The part I dont undestand would be further down in the proof right after the inductive assumption. I can try to write up how I got to this point if you want (I'm new to writing the code that makes the equations, i apologize for being so slow)

Comment: Rather than adding an answer, you should instead edit your question and fill-in the details to avoid other helpers being confused by what you are asking for.

Comment: ok.... I will do that in the future.....thanks

Comment: Mufasa.....I'm still not really getting the simplification. Do you know of a resource that I could look at that might explain it to me. I find my text book to be a terrible resource.  I don't want to bug you guys since I don't seem to be getting it.

Comment: Maybe these might be useful to you: [Strong induction - PDF](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~stephens/203/PDF/4-4.pdf) and [Strong induction MIT lecture](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/video-lectures/lecture-3-strong-induction/)

Comment: @Mufasa Awesome! Thanks so much for your help!!